# Getting NERR_DfsNoSuchVolume (Error code:2662) while checking DFS share path

Tags: c#, wmi, microsoft-distributed-file-system, fileserver, distributed-filesystem

I have an exe (C# application) which runs with a service account and tried to get the DSF link for a file share. Share exists and accessible. i have another similar exe running with the same service account and running fine where as my exe is not getting 2662 error. I compared the both the exe and they are similar but existing exe is not getting that 2662 error. What are the things i can check for that exe to check on this 2662 error code.

```
Input : \\consto.com\myfolder\folder1
Output: \\BZ1GHT12NM\myfolder\folder1
```

int Error = NetDfsGetClientInfo(DFSPath, null, null, 3, out Buffer);
Error code : 2662
NERR_DfsNoSuchVolume There is no volume whose entry path matches the input entry path. 2662

#region Import

```
    [DllImport("Netapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "NetApiBufferFree")]
    public static extern uint NetApiBufferFree(IntPtr Buffer);

    [DllImport("Netapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int NetDfsGetInfo(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string EntryPath,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string ServerName,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string ShareName,
        int Level,
        out IntPtr Buffer);

    [DllImport("Netapi32.dll")]
    public static extern int NetDfsGetClientInfo(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string EntryPath,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string ServerName,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string ShareName,
        int Level,
        out IntPtr Buffer);

    #endregion

    #region Structures

    public struct DFS_INFO_3
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string EntryPath;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string Comment;
        public UInt32 State;
        public UInt32 NumberOfStorages;
        public IntPtr Storages;
    }

    public struct DFS_STORAGE_INFO
    {
        public Int32 State;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string ServerName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string ShareName;
    }

    #endregion

    const int DFS_VOLUME_STATE_OK = 0x00000001;
    const int DFS_VOLUME_STATE_ONLINE = 0x00000004;
    const int DFS_STORAGE_STATE_ONLINE = 0x00000002;
    const int DFS_STORAGE_STATE_ACTIVE = 0x00000004;

    public static String GetSharePath(String DFSPath)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(DFSPath))
        {
            IntPtr Buffer = IntPtr.Zero;
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User : {0}, Domain= {1}",Environment.UserName, Environment.UserDomainName);
                Console.WriteLine("Path is {0}", DFSPath);
                int Error = NetDfsGetClientInfo(DFSPath, null, null, 3, out Buffer);
                Console.WriteLine("Error code {0}", Error);
                if (Error == 0)
                {
                    DFS_INFO_3 DFSInfo = (DFS_INFO_3)Marshal.PtrToStructure(Buffer, typeof(DFS_INFO_3));
                    if ((DFSInfo.State & DFS_VOLUME_STATE_OK) > 0)
                    {
                        String SubPath = DFSPath.Remove(0, 1 + DFSInfo.EntryPath.Length).TrimStart(new Char[] { '\\' });
                        for (int i = 0; i < DFSInfo.NumberOfStorages; i++)
                        {
                            IntPtr Storage = new IntPtr(DFSInfo.Storages.ToInt64() + i * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DFS_STORAGE_INFO)));
                            DFS_STORAGE_INFO StorageInfo = (DFS_STORAGE_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(Storage, typeof(DFS_STORAGE_INFO));
                            if ((StorageInfo.State & DFS_STORAGE_STATE_ACTIVE) > 0)
                            {
                                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(SubPath))
                                {
                                    return String.Format(@"\\{0}\{1}", StorageInfo.ServerName, StorageInfo.ShareName);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    return (String.Format(@"\\{0}\{1}\{2}", StorageInfo.ServerName, StorageInfo.ShareName, SubPath));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (Error == 2662)
                    return DFSPath;
            }
            finally
            {
                NetApiBufferFree(Buffer);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String GetShareName(String SharePath)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SharePath))
        {
            String[] Tokens = SharePath.Trim(new Char[] { '\\' }).Split(new Char[] { '\\' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (2 <= Tokens.Length)
                return Tokens[1];
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using similar code that works or fails on different machines.  The key thing seems
to be that the NetDFSGetClientInfo doesn't actually have access to the information unless the path has been previously referenced. So it works if I have a drive mapped, or even if recently looked at the location with file explorer.  But if I disconnect drive mappings and restart my machine, I get the error.

I Just put in code to create a directoryinfo object for the path before I try the
call to NetDFSGetClientInfo.  So far it seems make it work....